# styled-components/macro isn't working with CRA

Tags: styled-components

When i install a new `create-react-app` and add `babel-plugin-styled-components` and add displayName option to `babel-plugin-macros.config.js` it isn't adding readable classNames as in the documentation -> https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-macro.

Here is a repo with the configurations https://github.com/Futekov3216/CRA.git

P.S i dont want to eject

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Today I myself faced such a problem. The problem lies in `styled-components` itself. Macro in styled does not work since version 5.2.2, and it is not known when it will be fixed. Simplest solution:

```
npm i styled-components@5.2.1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

This problem still persists in styled-components v5.3.3. Visit [this](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3645) to know more about the issue. At this moment you can install styled-components@5.2.1 as mentioned by @mxpv for getting the Component's name along with generated classes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The issue causing this problem [has been resolved](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3635).

Ensure that the version of [babel-plugin-styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/babel-plugin-styled-components) has at least version 2.0.3 by installing the package (as a dev dependency). The macro should work with the latest version of Styled-Components.

```
npm install -D babel-plugin-styled-components
--or--
yarn add -D babel-plugin-styled-components
```

Comment: Thanks, this works on styled-components v6 as well